package ‘CAM’ is not available for this version of R
I want to install.packages("CAM"). But I get a wrong message:
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/14047/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘CAM’ is not available for this version of R
A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
How to fix the problem?

Welcome to SO!  Why do you believe the message is wrong?  Are you able to install the package from the archive?

You can install the package using the following code
install.packages("mboost")

install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/CAM/CAM_1.0.tar.gz", 
                 repo=NULL, type="source")

